# Integration and unit normal

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $G\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a an open bounded set with smooth boundary,$f:\text{closure(}G)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is $C^1$,and $u\in S^{n-1}$ constant vector.

Prove that $\int_{\partial G}<u,n>f(x)dS=\int_G\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} dx$ where $n(x)$ is then exterior unit normal to $\partial G$.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply the divergence theorem [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) to the vectorial function $g(x)=f(x)u$.

**Edit**
More details. You have $$\text{div} g=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}u_i=\nabla f\cdot u=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$$
and $g\cdot n=f u\cdot n$.

Comment: Could you please ellaborate and show me how?

Comment: I added more details, but when you ask a question, the SE rule is that you should write what you have tried to do and where you got stuck.